# Read Twitter users from a text file

Tags: java, performance, twitter

I have this code for reading Twitter users from a text file represented by integers in the format "int (space) int", where the first `int` is the ID of
the user doing the following and the second `int` is the user being followed. It works for small files but takes a really long time with larger files. What can I do to make it more efficient?

`users` is an `ArrayList`

```
public void open() {
    try {
        if (file.exists()) {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
            String[] strings;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                strings = line.split(" ");
                String user1 = strings[0];
                String user2 = strings[1];

                if (!users.toString().contains(user1)) {
                    TwitterUser tUser1 = new TwitterUser(
                            Integer.parseInt(user1));
                    users.add(tUser1);
                    TwitterUser tUser2 = new TwitterUser(
                            Integer.parseInt(user2));
                    tUser1.follow(tUser2);
                } else {
                    TwitterUser target = null;
                    for (TwitterUser i : users)
                        if (i.toString().equals(user1))
                            target = i;
                    TwitterUser tUser3 = new TwitterUser(
                            Integer.parseInt(user2));
                    target.follow(tUser3);

                }

            }
            fileReader.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some helpful answers.

Comment: Please include the definition of `users`.

Comment: private ArrayList<TwitterUser> users = new ArrayList<TwitterUser>();

Answer (score 4):

```
users.toString().contains(user1)
```

This is not a very optimal way of checking if a user from the file is in your `users` object. For starters, `ArrayList.toString()` will generate the `String` representation every time, and you may run into false positives. For example, if the `toString()` representation of a `TwitterUser` contains a comma, which is the delimiter used by `ArrayList`:

```
String user1 = user1.toString(); // = "John, Doe"
String user2 = user2.toString(); // = "Jane, Doe"
// Just to make sure we are using the ArrayList implementation
List<String> users = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(user1, user2));
String allUsers = users.toString(); // = "[John, Doe, Jane, Doe]"
allUsers.contains("Doe, Jane"); // = true
```

Sure, you are actually comparing numeric values, but consider this then:

```
String user11 = user11.toString(); // = "11"
String user22 = user22.toString(); // = "22"
// Just to make sure we are using the ArrayList implementation
List<String> users = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(user11, user22));
String allUsers = users.toString(); // = "[11, 22]"
allUsers.contains("1"); // = true
```

The point here is that ideally, your `TwitterUser` class should be constructed first so that you can use one of *its* method to test for equivalence, using `equals(Object)` for example:

```
public class TwitterUser {

    // ...

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // assuming id is a primitive value
        return o instanceof TwitterUser && ((TwitterUser) o).id == id;
    }
}
```

Again, you should avoid using `toString()`-based comparison below for testing equivalence due to the 'false positives' point. Furthermore, you should not skimp on braces (`{ ... }`), and `break` early once you have a match:

```
for (TwitterUser i : users) {
    TwitterUser twitterUser = // ...
    if (i.equals(twitterUser)) {
        target = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

**Hold your horses!** If you have implemented `TwitterUser.equals()` to compare by the ID, you wouldn't even need the `for`-loop:

```
TwitterUser user = new TwitterUser(Integer.parseInt(user1));
if (!users.contains(user)) {
    users.add(user);
    user.follow(new TwitterUser(Integer.parseInt(user2)));
} else {
    TwitterUser currentUser = users.get(users.indexOf(user));
    currentUser.follow(new TwitterUser(Integer.parseInt(user2)));
}
```

**To make the performance better, you can consider using a `Set` instead of a `List`.**

To avoid the huge nested `if`-block after `if (file.exists())`, consider `return`-ing early:

```
public void open() {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Ideally, the `File` object should be passed to this method so that the method callers know what *exact* file is being opened here.

**edit:** If you claim that the processing still *tends to infinity*, consider reworking your process:

1. Read all the lines from the file (even if it runs into the millions, it's just two numbers per line).
2. Use a number of background threads to process the lines concurrently. You'll need a `Runnable`/`Callable` implementation, an `ExecutorService` and a thread-safe `Collection` implementation. This is probably more suited for another question/answer though...

Comment: I tried using your code and my program takes still takes infinite time to run. Could you show me an example of what the final code should look like? Thanks.

Comment: Define infinite. How large is your file? Millions of lines?

Comment: I'ts a 160MB text file. I'm saying infinite because it never actually runs, it keeps on loading forever.

Comment: See my edit. You may want to rework your process.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the if statement if (!users.contains(user))
If I remove it, the program seems to execute fine, but how do i get around that?

Comment: Then you should seriously consider switching to a `Set`, if possible. Checking if a `Set` contains an object is `O(1)`, whereas it's `O(n)` for `List`. For more info, see this [StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196343/hash-set-and-array-list-performances).